# Set::IntervalTree acting weirdly when I add nodes through a loop in perl

Tags: perl, interval-tree

I am trying to use the [`Set::IntervalTree`](https://metacpan.org/module/Set%3a%3aIntervalTree) module and I think it is giving me the same node pointers if I insert the elements in a loop.

If I insert them outside a loop sequentially one after the another the nodes are inserted fine and the `find` / `find_window` calls works perfectly. But on the nodes which were added in the loop, the find functions give strange results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Set::IntervalTree;
my $tree = Set::IntervalTree->new;

$tree->insert("60:70", 60, 70);
$tree->insert("70:80", 70, 80);
$tree->insert("80:90", 80, 90);

for(my $i = 0; $i < 60; $i=$i+10)
{
    $j = $i+10;
    print "$i".":"."$j\n";
    $tree->insert("$i".":"."$j", $i, $i+10);
}

print $tree->str;

my $results1 = $tree->fetch(25, 28);
my $window = $tree->fetch_window(25,250);
my @arr1 = @$results1;
print " @arr1 found.\n";

my $results2 = $tree->fetch(65, 68);
my @arr2 = @$results2;
print " @arr2 found.\n";
```

This is the output. Check the node pointers.. the ones added from the loop have same pointers and they return wrong interval (which i guess is due to the same pointer values.)

```
Node:0x9905b20, k=0, h=9, mH=9  l->key=NULL  r->key=NULL  p->key=10  color=BLACK
Node:0x9905b20, k=10, h=19, mH=29  l->key=0  r->key=20  p->key=30  color=RED
Node:0x9905b20, k=20, h=29, mH=29  l->key=NULL  r->key=NULL  p->key=10  color=BLACK
Node:0x9905b20, k=30, h=39, mH=89  l->key=10  r->key=70  p->key=NULL  color=BLACK
Node:0x9905b20, k=40, h=49, mH=49  l->key=NULL  r->key=NULL  p->key=50  color=RED
Node:0x9905b20, k=50, h=59, mH=69  l->key=40  r->key=60  p->key=70  color=BLACK
Node:0x98c6270, k=60, h=69, mH=69  l->key=NULL  r->key=NULL  p->key=50  color=RED
Node:0x98fd138, k=70, h=79, mH=89  l->key=50  r->key=80  p->key=30  color=RED
Node:0x98fd078, k=80, h=89, mH=89  l->key=NULL  r->key=NULL  p->key=70  color=BLACK

 50:60 found.
 60:70 found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to use a Perl scalar variable if you are calling `insert` from an inner block. If you use an interpolated string it will be discarded and overwritten by the subsequent execution of the block.

This code seems to work fine. Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` on all your programs - particularly those you are asking for help with.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Set::IntervalTree;
my $tree = Set::IntervalTree->new;

for (my $i = 0; $i <= 80; $i += 10) {
    my $name = sprintf '%02d:%02d', $i, $i+10;
    $tree->insert($name, $i, $i+10);
}

my $results1 = $tree->fetch(25, 28);
print "@$results1 found\n";

my $results2 = $tree->fetch(65, 68);
print "@$results2 found\n";
```

**output**

```
20:30 found
60:70 found
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used this package. the C++ code for insert has arguments (&t, int, int). this means that the C++ code store away a pointer to the perl data
for the first argument. using a scalar is not really a solution. eventually
the value will be overwritten. the solution i used was to put the id into a
hash and pass the hash value as the id. this will keep around the perl data
for the id. the C++ code should copy the id to maintain its value.

```
$id = "$start:$end";
$rephash1{$id} = $id;
$repeats1{$scaffold} = Set::IntervalTree->new if (!defined($repeats1{$scaffold}));
$repeats1{$scaffold}->insert($rephash1{$id}, $start, $end);
```